# One multi-dimensional array vs. multiple tables with joined rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization, multidimensional-array

I'm building a lists website (nothing special, people can just create lists for example 'movies to watch', or 'to do' but it's good to learn things).

**The current situation**:
People sign up, I create a row for them in the `users` table. In that row, I have a column named `Lists`. In this column I store a `serialized array` that is structured like this:

```
$lists = array(
            "To Do" => array(
                                "List Info" => array(
                                                    "add date" => 20170503,
                                                    "add time" => 130530
                                                    ),
                                array(
                                                    "item" => "Go to the supermarket",
                                                    "add date" => 20170503,
                                                    "add time" => 140503,
                                                    "completed" => false
                                                    ),
                                array(
                                                    "item" => "Clean my room",
                                                    "add date" => 20170503,
                                                    "add time" => 180503,
                                                    "completed" => false
                                                    ),
                                array(
                                                    "item" => "Go jogging",
                                                    "add date" => 20170503,
                                                    "add time" => 200503,
                                                    "completed" => true
                                                    )
                            ),
            "Movies To Watch" => array(
                                "List Info" => array(
                                                    "add date" => 20170504,
                                                    "add time" => 130530
                                                    ),
                                array(
                                                    "item" => "Zootopia",
                                                    "add date" => 20170504,
                                                    "add time" => 150503,
                                                    "completed" => true
                                                    ),
                                array(
                                                    "item" => "Anne The Series",
                                                    "add date" => 20170504,
                                                    "add time" => 190503,
                                                    "completed" => false
                                                    ),
                                array(
                                                    "item" => "Upside Down",
                                                    "add date" => 20170505,
                                                    "add time" => 230503,
                                                    "completed" => false
                                                    )
                            )
         );
```

This works fine, but I was wondering if it's the right way to do it. Especially since I want to store some information about every list and item (`add date`, `add time`, and eventually more..)

Would it be better to make multiple tables: `users`, `lists`, `list items` and then inner join them by user ID?

I was also kinda wondering how big social media websites do this... for example Twitter. Do they add a new row for every tweet or do they push a new tweet into the array... or something else?

Any advice would be very appreciated,

Nathan

Comment: Short answer: Of course it would be better to make multiple tables. Take a look at any database primer, there must be thousands you can google. Your approach really doesn't scale. (How would you ever search for a tweet, for example?)

Comment: Yeah, I actually had a search function and I would just unserialize all users arrays and get the matching list items... it wasn't slow but I can imagine it to be with over 1000 users. ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach would be to create the separate tables like you mentioned. (`users`, `lists`, `list_items`)

Your relationships would be like this:

`users` -> `lists` = linked by `user_id` column in both tables

`lists` -> `list_items`= linked by `list_id` column in both tables

This would also give you the ability for users to have multiple lists without the need for an extra column in your users table.

If you were to continue adding the list items into a serialized array then once the array starts to grow to a certain size you will encounter performance issues because you have a huge column entry to sort through.

Databases are pretty performant these days at looking through million even billions of rows in good time. Just remember to have indexes on all of the fields which tables join on.

You could argue the point about that `LONGBLOB` field allowing 4GB of text, but it will take a hell of a long time to load that single record. Storing them as rows gives you the flexibility of only retrieving the rows you need at the time. Rather than all of them every time you need even just one

To answer your question about twitter, yes they will have a new row for every tweet.

Quote from comments by [alexis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/699305/alexis) which I feel is of value:

> Google "normalization" and you'll see that the very first step ("first
>   normal form") is to store only one value in each cell. If you can
>   imagine any scenarios where you'll want to query the database for a
>   single setting, give them all their own column. If the contents of the
>   settings are completely transparent to the database, and especially if
>   they are semi-structured (e.g., a varying set of key-value pairs),
>   then it might be justifiable to keep the database ignorant of what the
>   settings are (i.e. to do what you're doing now).

**Some useful links on Database Normalization**

- http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php
- https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I see how it would be more convenient but I thought it would take more time to look through all these rows than loop through one array.

Comment: Size doesn't seem a problem right? If I just use a LONGBLOB data type? That's upto 4GB of text.

Comment: Databases are pretty performant these days at looking through million even billions of rows in good time. Just remember to have indexes on all of the fields which tables join on.

You could argue the point about that allowing 4GB of text, but it will take a hell of a long time to load that single record. Storing them as rows gives you the flexibility of only retrieving the rows you need at the time. Rather than all of them every time you need even just one

Comment: Okay well, I'm glad I got an answer but at the same time pretty annoyed I have to refactor my whole site lol. :P

Comment: It's the best investment of time you'll make for the future of your site. If you feel the answer helped you, please consider accepting it :)

Comment: You're absolutely right about that! Will do that in 5 minutes, can't do it yet! Thanks

Comment: @Nathan it's good that you thought to ask, even in this late-ish stage. Better now than when a website is actually in heavy use with lots of data...

Comment: @alexis Yeah that's true! ;-) Working on it right now. I still had a question though, should I still use `serialize($array)` for things such as `'account_settings'`, and array that doesn't get longer but just stores user preferences, such as `background_color` etc...?

Comment: There's nothing to say you can't do it, but again, account settings tend to be a column for each value, using the theory before if everything is a row or column, you can then access that individual property/value without having to retrieve every one of them when you may just need one. If your site ends up scaling you need to employ this sort of data granularity as it will aid performance greatly in a scaled environment

Comment: Google "normalization" and you'll see that the very first step ("first normal form") is to store only one value in each cell. If you can imagine any scenarios where you'll want to query the database for a single setting, give them all their own column. If the contents of the settings are completely transparent to the database, and especially if they are semi-structured (e.g., a set of key-value pairs that varies with time and by user), then it might be justifiable to keep the database ignorant of what the settings are (i.e. to do what you're doing now).

Comment: But for arbitrary key-value data you can just design a separate "key store" table, with columns (user, key, value). So what matters is if the data is hard to model in the database *and* there will never be any queries that will depend on the data. In other words, the reasonable thing is to always use the capabilities of your relational database as much as possible, until you have a compelling reason to bypass them.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you will be better of if you use different tables.
Otherwise you are limiting the number of lists / contents to the size of the field.

Comment: An external file can hold even more, but I thought your question was in the context of a relational database. It seems your plan was to use mysql as a mongo db.